# Test for intermittent communication drops between machines

Tags: networking, diagnostic

I am trying to diagnose intermittent communication drops between a computer and another networked piece of equipment. Can someone recommend me any tool or method to do this? Sure I can set up a ping test but was wondering if there was a better method of doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best, easiest and cheapest method is a ping test with a count of at least 100 pings. Specify the bytes after drawing some conclusion to see whether the loss is due to data sizes. Start the assessment at the network and then work your way to the suspect pieces of equipment.

windows: ping /?
1.) windows: ping -n 100 x.x.x.
2.) windows: ping -n 100 -1 1500 x.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

check traffic using wireshark. There you could find RST messages in case there're incompatible settings (half duplex on one side, full duplex on the other... things like that)